# Who maintains View and ViewNavigator? Adobe AIR or Apache Flex

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5

Now that the responsibility for Flex has been given to Apache, I am unclear on who has responsibility for components of Flex that are also part of Adobe Air.  This includes classes such as spark.components.View, and spark.components.ViewNavigator.  These are both part of Adobe Air, and part of Flex.

I am running Apache Flex 4.9.1, which includes Apache Air 3.4. But, I have overlaid onto this Apache Air 3.8.  When I look at the source code, I see the Apache 4.9.1 versions of View and ViewNavigator.  But, when I execute the code, I suspect that I am really running instances of View and ViewNavigator from inside the Air 3.8 runtime.  Is this correct?  If it is correct it makes debugging very difficult.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about who maintains code; which is not a programming question.

Comment: They are part of the Flex Framework and were donated to Apache, so Apache is the formal "owner".  The components you mention have a dependency on AIR; but AIR has no dependency on those components.  Josh's answer describes this in much more depth. I don't understand why running Adobe AIR 3.8 with Apache Flex 4.9.1 makes debugging difficult.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Apache AIR". It is Adobe AIR. The Flash and AIR SDKs are solely maintained by Adobe while the Flex SDK is solely maintained by Apache (Adobe donated it to Apache in 2011). When you install the Flex SDK and it installs AIR 3.4, that is a nearly year old SDK that they are shipping with it (the current version is 3.8 which was released in the last few weeks).

As for `View` and `ViewNavigator`, those are Flex components. They have absolutely nothing to do with the AIR SDK. You have your dependencies mixed up here. Flex components that require an AIR project to run, require classes found within the AIR SDK; they are not actually part of the AIR SDK. More specifically, View and ViewNavigator require a *mobile* AIR project as there are classes found within that specific section of the SDK that those two components require. So anything found within the `spark` or `mx` packages are Flex components and **not** AIR components. AIR itself does not add any additional GUI objects as far as I am aware, only support classes. **Update** As mentioned by RIAStar, this is not entirely true. AIR adds two classes to the `flash.display` package, `NativeWindow` and `NativeMenu`

In most cases, your project will not even compile if there is a class name conflict, so this is likely not an issue.

Comment: Just a minor correction: AIR does add two additional GUI elements which are in the `flash.display` package, i.e. `NativeWindow` and `NativeMenu`.

Comment: @RIAstar Good call. I had actually thought those were Flex components. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks. I have confirmed what you describe by looking inside the AIRSDK and identifying the classes that are in its swc's.  But, you must admit that it is confusing since Adobe API documentation marks the mobile components, like View and ViewNavigator as part of Air.  (FYI my reference to Apache Air was a typo).

Comment: +1 from me for the eloquent answer.  What Adobe documentation marks the mobile components as part of AIR?

Comment: @GaryGriswold No, they never mark them as *part of AIR*. They mark them as *requiring AIR*. There is a major difference. The components require AIR, but they are not included in the AIR SWCs. You can find them in the Flex source files, instead. This is no different than downloading a component from Reboog/Flextras (I highly recommend at least reading his blog) site that *requires* the Flex SDK. Without it, it cannot run. But it is not *included* within the Flex SDK